# Netsuite Advanced PDF/HTML add custom column if value

Tags: html, pdf, if-statement, netsuite, suitescript

I need help with adding a custom column with id 'item.custcol_new_unit_price'.

If there is a value for this column on any item, I need this column to appear on the printed form. I would think it would be something like this:

```
<td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.custcol_new_unit_price>${item.custcol_new_unit_price}</#if></td>
```

Any assistance would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.custcol_new_unit_price?has_content>${item.custcol_new_unit_price}</#if></td>
```

Source: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html

Comment: It looks like this would work when I look at the template, however I do not see it show up when I print the transaction. I tried replacing the field with "test" and it still does not show up.

Comment: If you remove the conditional all together does it print? Just: `<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.custcol_new_unit_price}</td>`?

Comment: This works! Thanks. Also, how would I hide a column if a certain item was on the invoice? If "Item A" is on the invoice, I need to hide "Unit Price". Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Is this field being displayed in the UI? If you want a custom field to be available in Advanced PDF/HTML Templates, it needs to be checked to "Show" in the Screen Fields tab when you customize the form. If you don't want the field visible in the UI, you can usually trick the system to hide it by making the Label empty.